# Receiving an error trying to use ggsave after ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpairs

I created a correlation plot:

```
library(nycflights13)
ggpairs(flights) +
  ggsave(filename = paste("overall_corr_plot.png"), path = paste(getwd(), "/images", sep = ""))
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in `+.gg`(ggpairs(flights), ggsave(filename = paste("overall_corr_plot.png"),  :                                                        
  'ggmatrix' does not know how to add objects that do not have class 'theme' or 'labels'. Received object with class: 'NULL'
In addition: There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

It seems it's missing some data. Is it possible to fix this and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't adding `ggsave` to your plot, which is what the `+` denotes here. Just call `ggsave` after running your plot, it automatically saves the last plot sent to your graphics device.

```r
ggpairs(flights)
ggsave(filename = paste("overall_corr_plot.png"), path = paste(getwd(), "/images", sep = ""))
```

Note that `ggpairs` on the entire `flights` data is going to be madness and you will have to drastically increase the `cardinality_threshold`, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Is it possible to first zoom? This seems to cut off some of the data that is exposed when I zoom on the plot in the output window doing it on a bigger frame with more variables.